# Copy an array into another array

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

```
char arrA[ 6 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0 };
char arrB[ 6 ] = {};
 
void setup(){
  strcpy( arrB, arrA );
}
```

Hi all, I obtained the code above from [here](http://arduino.land/FAQ/content/6/30/en/how-to-copy-an-array.html). My case is I need to use int arrA[6] instead of char arrA[6] when initializing variables so that it remains as values and not string. May I ask how do I actually accomplish it with arduino code. The link above only uses string as array and not numbers. Thank you for reading and have a nice day !!!

Comment: The `str` prefix in `strcpy` means it copies ***null-terminated** strings*. And `arrA` is not a null-terminated string. Use `memcpy` instead. Or `std::copy` since you're programming for Arduino which is using C++ (and that will also work well even if you have two arrays of different types).

Comment: _"I need to use int arrA[6] instead of char arrA[6] when initializing variables so that it remains as values and not string"_ - Are you sure you are asking the correct question? Shouldn't you ask how to print the values of `char`s instead ... or what's the problem keeping them as `char`s?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the array does end with a null (though that may be accidental rather than deliberate) so `strcpy` could be used (though fixed length copies are definitely more appropriate)

Comment: The initializer `{}` in not valid C (you may be using an extension). For compatability use `{0}` which works in C and, I believe, in C++. BTW: writing multi-language source files is very hard work. I suggest you stick to a single language.

Comment: >`The initializer {} in not valid C. ` sure, but arduino is C++

Answer (score -1):

You can write a `for` loop to copy the contents of `arrA` to `arrB`.

```
int arrA[ 6 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0 };
int arrB[ 6 ];
 
void setup(){
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(arrA[0])); i++)
    {
        arrB[i] = arrA[i];
    }
}
```